# how can i show a gridview on a page and then a listview on the same page

Tags: asp.net

Im new to this and need some info.
I want to make a gridview and a listview on the same page, but do i same em in 2 functions or 2 subs.

And how do i call the function/sub, when visit the page, the default show is Gridview, and then i have a icon under that, so when i click that its calling the listview function/sub.
Or do i call the gridview and listview and then use GridView1.Visible = false or ListView1.Visible = false to show/hide views !?

So.
1. Sub or Function.
2. How do i call the Gridview as default view when first visit, and how do i call the listview, with the icon. If then Else or !?

Im coding in asp.net VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PlaceHolder control`

```
PlaceHolder.Control.Add(YourGridView);
```

Or

```
 PlaceHolder.Control.Add(YourListView);
```

Nota : you can also load two controls and adjust `Visible property`

Sample :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" /> 
<asp:Button   
         ID="Button1"   
         runat="server"   
         Text="Add Control"   
         OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
        var YourGridView = .....;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(YourGridView);  
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In your .aspx-file you create both, the ListView and the GridView but set the Visible-Attribute of your ListView to false. In the Click-EventHandler of your icon you can then set the visibility of the ListView to true and the visibility of the GridView to false and vice versa.